# Comparing current and next element of array and returning time difference

Tags: javascript, arrays, momentjs

This is my array. Its length is about 9000. This is what a small bit of it looks like:

```
foreach_arr = ["21:07:01.535", "21:07:01.535", "21:07:26.113"]
```

There are a few occurences where the times diff is greater than a minute, and that is when I want to grab those times. And later use those times to get certain indices from another array. i.e "array"
I'm also using moment.js for time parsing.

Expected result:  `array = [8127, 9375, 13166, 14182]`

Actual result: `array = [8127, 13166]`

Can't seem to find the issue here, I am getting 2 results when im supposed to be getting 4.
If the whole array is needed for troubleshooting, ill add it if I can.

```
var xx = foreach_arr.length - 1;
for(var z = 0; z < xx; z++) {

    var current_row = foreach_arr[z];
    var next_row = foreach_arr[z + 1];

    var msElapsedTime = moment(next_row,"HH:mm:ss.SSS").diff(moment(current_row, "HH:mm:ss.SSS")) / 1000;

    if(msElapsedTime > 60) {
        attempt_indices.push(foreach_arr[z]);
    }

}

for(var x = 0; x < attempt_indices.length; x++) {
    array.push(newdata.indexOf(attempt_indices[x]));
}
```

Comment: The `Date` object should be one big step in the right direction, unless you want to do a lot of interesting string parsing for the date. Look into what the various methods are for it on the MDN docs.

Comment: @Andrew Did that, still same results, var current_row_date = new Date(year, month - 1, day, hour, minute, second, milisecond);
var next_row_date = new Date(year, month - 1, day, hour, minute, second, milisecond);
 var msElapsedTime = (next_row_date.getTime() - current_row_date.getTime()) / 1000;

Comment: Put more of the array in the question please. That would help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out my code wasn't wrong. Just my idea of the whole proccess.

array = [8127, 13166]

is what I initialy get. With this, I use indexOf on my other array to eventually get my array as expected:

```
                var another_test_arr = [];
                for(var v = 0; v < array.length ; v++) {
                var find = foreach_arr.indexOf(attempt_indices[v]);
                another_test_arr.push(array[v], newdata.indexOf(foreach_arr[find + 1]));
            }
```

Result: array = [8127, 9375, 13166, 14182]

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP doesn't really need my code anymore, I'm posting it here to remove the downvote as much as anything else :)

```
const foreach_arr = ["21:07:01.535", "21:07:01.535", "21:07:26.113", '22:01:01.000'];
let processedForeach_arr = [];
let gtOneMinuteDiff = [];

foreach_arr.forEach((elem1, index1) => {
  // elem1.split(':') turns foreach_arr[0] into ['21', '07', '01.535']
  const splitElementArray = elem1.split(':');
  let timeInMs = 0;
  // this changes ['21', '07', '01.535'] into [75600000, 420000, 1535]
  splitElementArray.forEach((elem2, index2) => {
    if (index2 === 0) { // elem2 is hours. 3.6M ms per hour.
      timeInMs += parseFloat(elem2) * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    } else if (index2 === 1) { // elem2 is minutes. 60K ms per minute.
      timeInMs += parseFloat(elem2) * 60 * 1000;
    } else if (index2 === 2) { // elem2 is seconds. 1K ms per second.
      timeInMs += parseFloat(elem2) * 1000;
    } else {
      throw `Expected array element formatted like HH:MM:SS.ms. Error on 
      element ${elem1}.`;
    }
  });
  processedForeach_arr.push(timeInMs);
  let timeDiff = processedForeach_arr[index1 - 1] - processedForeach_arr[index1];
  if (Math.abs(timeDiff) > 60000) {
    gtOneMinuteDiff.push(timeDiff);
  }
});
```

To get the difference in milliseconds between foreach_arr[n] and foreach_arr[n+1], this code will

1. split each element of foreach_arr into 3 strings (hours, minutes, and seconds + milliseconds)
2. run parseFloat on each of those values to convert them to a number
3. convert all numbers to milliseconds and add them together
4. compare each consecutive value and return the difference.

Ok, I got this far and my son needs me. I'll finish out the code asap but you might beat me to it, hopefully the instructions above help.

Comment: You should avoid including personal détails in your answers.

Comment: @AravindSuresh who cares? Your username is your full name. So is mine. I have a son. Big whoop. Don't downvote me for something trivial like that.

Comment: The reason I downvoted was because there was no code.

Comment: That's valid. I figured it would be better for the OP to have guidance than nothing, since no one else is answering him/her. But I'll be updating my answer in a few minutes, at which point please remove your downvote.

Comment: @AravindSuresh would you remove your downvote now? There is code in my answer.